# Sqoop export to sql server error

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I want to export hdfs file to sql server. I'm using sqoop for that

```
sqoop export --bindir . --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://server;database=db" --username sa --password pwd --table sqoop_test -m 1 --export-dir /user/sqooptest
```

but i get the following error.

```
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
sqoop export --bindir . --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://server;database=db" --username sa --password pwd --table sqoop_test -m 1 --export-dir /user/sqooptest

Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
16/07/30 03:59:06 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
16/07/30 03:59:07 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/07/30 03:59:07 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
16/07/30 03:59:07 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
16/07/30 03:59:07 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM [sqoop_test] AS t WHERE 1=0
16/07/30 03:59:07 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0
Note: ./sqoop_test.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
16/07/30 03:59:10 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: ./sqoop_test.jar
16/07/30 03:59:10 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3813)
    at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3800)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListingNoSort(FileListing.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListingNoSort(FileListing.java:82)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListingNoSort(FileListing.java:82)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListing(FileListing.java:67)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListing(FileListing.java:39)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager.addClassFilesFromDir(CompilationManager.java:284)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager.jar(CompilationManager.java:346)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:109)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:64)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:100)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

the file has only 3 rows with three columns each. it has no null values. I tried using --input-null-string as well.

my sql table :

```
create table sqoop_test
(id int,
name nvarchar(200),
title nvarchar(200))
```

and the file content in hdfs is,

```
5,X,analyst
6,Y,architect
7,Z,lead
```

Comment: did you try `--fields-terminated-by` and/or `--lines-terminated-by ` ?  - your file's fields may be are not delimited by sqoop's default delimiters (comma (,) for fields, a newline (\n)) - can you show us content of your file?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: Are you trying to export table in particular schema? Under which schema this RDBMS table created?

Comment: Dear friends, how do you guys fix the problem??